# How to setup old iPhone for development testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've got an older iPhone 3Gs, and I've just joined the Apple developer program. The phone isn't active, and I don't have a SIM card in it (the SIM is in my current phone). I've gone through the provisioning portal with it and setup the certificates, but I can't seem to use it for development. I'm getting the error: "This device is not activated. It must be activated before it can be used with Xcode". When I try to activate the phone, it says "please insert SIM card". I don't want to use the one I have in my active phone...

I know for sure it doesn't have to be activated with a carrier to develop on thanks to another question asked on here. Is it possible to get a SIM card to just activate the phone so I can test on it? How else would I go about activating the phone?

Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, I moved my SIM card from my real phone to a test phone just to activate it, then moved it back when done. Nothing bad happened, and the test phone continued to work without a SIM after that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I'll try to move my SIM over for the activation process and then move it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cariers will supply you with a free sim card (at least here in the uk they will). Rather that try to circumnavigate the issue, the most simple solution would be to order a sim card that you reserve for development.

You can probably activate the phone by just switching the sim from your other phone over to do the activation process, but you might find it useful for testing if you have a sim in the phone when developing so that you cant test call interruptions etc.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a SIM card to do development on an iPhone, but you **do** need a SIM card to activate the device. Another option would be to jailbreak it.